# Converting PDF417 codewords/binary array to ID Automation Barcode Font code

Tags: ruby, barcode, barcode-printing, pdf417, rsbarcodes

I am working on a rails application that needs to send an piece of HL7 data encoded as PDF417 as JSON over API. The receiver of the barcode encoding will then insert the data into a word document with a PDF417 IDAutomation barcode font.

The problem I am running into is providing an encoding that the font likes.

I've used several encoders, Barby, https://github.com/asee/pdf417, https://github.com/asee/pdf417, which produce arrays of integers(codewords) via text compaction, binary compaction, etc, but all of these are different than what the IDAutomation font expects. Using their encoders it creates a list of 11 rows of numbers 324 chars each.

I seem to be missing a key piece of information here, but having trouble finding the explanation. I found a clue regarding getting the right error correction, row count, and column count values, but it still seems to be a big disconnect between what ID Automation font wants, and these ruby barcode encoders produce. (An array of binary, or an array of codewords)

For example with Barby:
Binary:

```
 => ["11111111010101000111010110111100001100100000100110011101100100011000111000110110111001110010001000111010010001000010000100001101110011001101001000001100011101010111000000110000110001000101010011101110000010101000001000000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111111010110111101110101110000011011110101110011100110101110000100001000011101011111011100000100011010100001110101111101011111010000111011100011001110100111100010000010101111101100100010011110101101100000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000110101000011111001100011111010001010000111100100010100000110010011101101010111110000010101000111100000111100101111010001101100001001111011111010111001000100011101100011101000111011000111010101100111110000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000101001000010000001000010011101110011110011101001100111101111010001001100011000010010010001100110010000101100111000110001100001100010001011000011011001100100010000110001101101110011000100011101001001110000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000110101111001100001011111010000111011000001001110010100010011111011001110011011101000010111110100001110100001110101111101110101110000011011110100000101000111010111001100001010111111011100011110101111011110111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111010111110010001000011110010001010001111000010100100001111001000101000011110010001010111111011100010101001100111110001111110010110001010111111011110110110110001011110001011001101111000011010111111001000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111101000101111001011011101100000011001100001100110101101110011000001011100111000100011101111000110010110100001100011101000110110001000010101100011000000111001100000101101110011011101111010100111100111100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111110100100001101011100010011111011101001100000010110011000011110101111010010010000011110101000100000101001111110111001100110001111010010100011110000100101000111100001001010001111000010011111010010001100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111111010011101101111001011110100011011010000011110100001101000111001111101000011101011001111010011000100011101110111101101111100010001010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111011111010011110110111111101000101001", "11111111010101000101000010010000001000010011101110011110011101001100100000100010001001100111001110011010000100111011100100001001110111001000010011101110011110011101001100100000100010001001110001100001011010100011110111100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000101001111001000001111000100000101011110001000001010111100010000010101111000100000101010001111001011110111000110011101001111000100000101011110001000001010111100010000010101111000100000101011010011110110000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000101000110011111001100111101001100010000001101011100110111110001001001101111100010010011011111000100100110111110001001001101111100010010011011111000100100100111100001001001000111011101111011110100011110010111111101000101001", "11111111010101000110100000100001101001110011100100010011100111001000100111001110010001100001100010001011000011000100010100001100110010001000010100010000011110011100101100100001000110001101101001100001110011101000001001110111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111010001100010001111011100011101011011101111100100110001101111010001111000010010010011010111110011100101111011011111001111000100000101011110001000001010111100010000010101111000100000101011101000110010000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000100101011110000001000111011000111010001110110001110110011110100110001000000110101110010011110000100100100011101110111101001111000010010010001110111011110100111100001001001000111011101111010010100011110000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000100101100001100001100111001110011010000100111011100100001001110111001100001100011011011001110011100110100001001110111001000010011101110010000100111011100110000110001101101001110011100100011001011001110000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111110100001001101000011101011111011100001000110100111000010001101001011110110111110011110001000001010100011110010111101110001100111010011110001000001010111110110010001001011111001000111011111010000101100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111001011111010001000000110100111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111011001011111100100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000110110110110000001111001110100110010000010001000100111000110000101101000010011101110010000110011100110111011100110011001111001100010111011100011011011100111001000100011101011001110011000011101101000001100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111010000011000101011110110111110011110001000001010100110001111101001100010111000010011110101110111000101111011011111001111000100000101011110001000001010111100010000010101111000100000101011110100000110110111111101000101001", "11111111010101000110010010001111101000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101100011111001010011011111000100100100001111001000101001111000010010011111100100110100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000100100111001110001000110111100111011100011000010110100001001110111001000010011101110011110011101001100100000100010001001000110001100001010001101111001110100111001110010001001110011100100010110111000011000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111001011001000001011110110111110011110001000001010111110110010001001000000101111010010011110010111100111100010000010101111000100000101011110001000001010111110110010001001011111001001110011110010110110000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111011011111100101000000110100111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010110010011100000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111011001100111001000010011101110010000100100000010101110111000010001101100001000010011100111010010000110011100111001101000010011101110010000100111011100100001001110111001000010011101110011001000100110000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000110010111100001101111000100000101011110001000001010111100010000010101101110001111101010111110100001110111000010001101001110001100111010011110001000001010111100010000010101111000100000101011001011110001100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000101100111001111101111100010011101010000011100101100100001111001000101000000110101110010011110000100100100011101110111101001111000010010010001110111011110100111100001001001000111011101111011101100111111010111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111011000101100001000110001100001010001101111001110100011000110000101000110111100111010001100011000010100011011110011101000110001100001010001101111001110110011100111001101000010010000001010010001110001110111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111101101100010001100010111000010011000100011110110110011000011110101101011100000100011110100100100000111101000100000101011110110111110011110001000001010111100010000010101111000100000101011111011011001100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000101100001000111001000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010110000010111000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000100100001100110001000010011101110010000100111011100100001001110111001000010011101110010000100111011100100001001110111001000010010000001010111011100001000110001000001001101110011101001000010110001100000100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000110110111100001001110000100011010011100001000110100111000010001101001011110110111110011111011001000100100111100010111101001111001011110011110001000001010100110001111101001100010111000010011011011110001000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000100010111011111101101110100011100010011110100100000110101011111000001111110010111011011010011111100010100011101000110001000010010111100011111001011101000100111101001000001010111000111111011000101111110100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000100100000100000101111001110100110010000110001100100100001100011001001000011000110010010000110001100100100001100011001001110111100110001011100010001001110100001000010100001011000011101100011001000001000110111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111110110010001001111010010001000011100010111000110101000111100010001001111101000111010111101001111000111000101100001001111000001010100011100010001100010111100010001001001110001101110010011111101100100110111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111111000100110101101001100111111010100000100011110101111011101110001010000100001111010001111000101000101001110111111001000111010110000011100010011111010110111110001010001011000011011110011111000100111010111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111000101100111101000011011000001011011011001100000101000001010000001110100111011111010011011110111000100001100111001101000101110111000011110011110100010100011100111000101110101101111000011000101101110000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000110110011110001001011111101001100011111000011010010111001110111100101101000011110110010110111111011000110000101110010001100110011110001010010011110000100111101000110110001111010111000111011011001111001000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000101110110111000001100111000101110011010011011111100111111010110001001000010011011111011101001011111100111001001011111101100110010111100011111010000111010101000000101111001100111110001001010111011000111000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111000100100111001000101110001110010111011110110000101000010001000001100110011100111011101110010100000111000110110111001100001101101100010011011100001100100011000110010001111011110110110011100010010111000111111101000101001"]
```

Other pdf417 text campaction codewords:

```
tc.compact_text
=> [7, 28, 25, 21, 29, 1, 8, 14, 8, 16, 28, 0, 1, 17, 0, 0, 25, 21, 29, 28, 2, 0, 1, 9, 1, 2, 1, 6, 25, 21, 29, 4, 28, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 21, 11, 15, 29, 15, 28, 25, 21, 29, 25, 28, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 9, 8, 0, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 29, 23, 19, 25, 23, 22, 23, 9, 1, 28, 25, 21, 29, 27, 20, 18, 4, 17, 6, 28, 24, 27, 20, 18, 4, 17, 6, 28, 24, 25, 21, 29, 28, 1, 9, 6, 8, 1, 1, 2, 2, 25, 21, 29, 12, 28, 25, 21, 21, 29, 28, 1, 2, 3, 4, 28, 26, 5, 8, 18, 7, 26, 7, 0, 19, 2, 7, 4, 17, 24, 26, 17, 3, 28, 25, 21, 29, 6, 0, 18, 19, 14, 13, 28, 25, 21, 29, 18, 2, 28, 25, 21, 29, 28, 2, 9, 0, 5, 3, 25, 21, 29, 28, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 25, 21, 29, 28, 0, 3, 25, 21, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 29, 28, 24, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 29, 28, 24, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 21, 21, 29, 23, 19, 25, 23, 22, 23, 9, 1, 28, 25, 21, 29, 23, 19, 25, 23, 22, 23, 9, 1, 28, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 29, 28, 24, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 21, 21, 21, 29, 28, 24, 25, 21, 21, 11, 15, 29, 2, 28, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 29, 28, 24, 25, 21, 21, 21, 29, 4, 17, 4, 16, 28, 25, 21, 29, 1, 8, 14, 8, 28, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 11, 15, 29, 0, 28, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 21, 21, 21, 11, 15, 29, 12, 28, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 11, 15, 29, 1, 28, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 11, 15, 29, 10, 28, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 11, 15, 29, 8, 28, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 25, 21, 11, 15, 29, 19, 28, 25, 21, 29, 28, 1, 8, 2, 9, 4, 9, 25, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 11, 15, 29, 18, 28, 25, 21, 29, 28, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 21, 11, 15, 29, 3, 28, 25, 21, 21, 21, 11, 15, 29, 11, 28, 25, 21, 29, 28, 0, 0, 5, 0, 2, 25, 21, 11, 15, 29, 4, 28, 25, 21, 29, 28, 0, 25, 21]
```

ID Automation encoding:

```
777777770707070007737352123166300076631353225166610734303675155600007111427613176322077740145751563460750112671207373307462673170014623076600377166364430764227111623264707206231512236203072202551566304630740621733221460107662617154430221076311157202731250704117660656332207440533422766013077771707415447400777777707000707007
777777770707070007574363351354550072313512245101460770433551033675207467512777271774076462315526366430725123004422375207723531663457220072657406674037100764401175263464107243110276220673074026137726740230702267312642323507651004714437752072652177441755110762661351203600107735245473154564077161273111541300777777707000707007
777777770707070007373074471114744075005377074633220750053770746332207500537707463322077205157054631200750013770306332607440537217563333074000377120722270740003771207222707004473356432623074000377120722270740003771207222707620037712272007076022355122722070760223551227220707602235512272207077372124135523000777777707000707007
777777770707070007735210263753230070266713744326230720445317663062107226653356410601070044733564326230722445335663040307026671374432623072044531766306210762220671214131407005573246432632070045732575237330700557324643263207000573217523337074451376424326720744017761712733307445177642432272077170122611550300777777707000707007
777777770707070007372030142315331074440377524326630744403775243266307664037752632443072026715566326470760223551227220707620215512270027074022177322502050762221751007022507400017532270205074000377120722270700447335643262307400037712072227070044733564326230700446235652373207400037712072227073702101621311510777777707000707007
777777770707070007772070551355651076000157122700250740003771207222707000077356472667074404773164326630744403771207266707440037716436663074400733160326670740442275612777207445137642432672074441376535237730744403775243266307445137642432672075441773434673220750017330346376607104177303067322071340563333154330777777707000707007
777777770707070007631611404621131077463355436237420774633554362374207302771547623746073027711076233060730277154762374607306771147623702073265711456015020752233750124332407700315503261106075203377210433040730277514766334607702335507627702073027751476633460730673554366330207742375143267302076334314004611310777777707000707007
777777770707070007336314652757330077473254426337520765337055626774607302765157772346072077355437723120760663111623224307642264516327312072215530044122160766411565152357107665137642632452076463354537237530764733544263265207646335453723753076473354426326520764633545372375307647335442632652077325124741155740777777707000707007
777777770707070007552072225115741073207717674017440730277110762330607302771547623746073027711076233060730277154762374607302771107623306077463355436237420774637514366730207702371103663746073063751032673020730237514722730207702335503263306073023351076233460774277114322374207306331547267702077502522271137450777777707000707007
777777770707070007277204655201577075441277535327620757633757141076207664015750432461076651157405324610767412665373244207656324553722642076642155526304630754620777361065107767317550530760077440057536324730744412664342377307555166343576322074011732124726660703637700035733107502313723601740076770460134075510777777707000707007
777777770707070007314201277155021072011772126623420722317500374027107301055313762162071323651317622500732235731246104107203377022672252073133562334511610712317733275225007111174323750071071112472337502610712307722355315007222275223561153073220461216511510712276334651335507237435772313773077126032375134450777777707000707007
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID Automation font is only going to "like" it's own proprietary encoding scheme, which appears to be using something similar to octal instead of the Barby binary or "tc" decimal. The three schemes all create different PDF417 barcodes with different number of rows and columns.

What you are running into is the stage gap between digitization and rendering. The digitization stage is responsible for turning data into the dots and spaces required for the specific symbology used (Code 128, PDF417, etc). The rendering stage is used to take the ones and zeros and turn those into ink or light up pixels.

You can't mix the two stages because the first stage creates the encoding in the format that the second stage needs.

I tried to convert the ID Automation encoding to binary from what I assumed was octal. It did not scan. The Barby binary encoding scanned like a champ.

```js
// The MIT License (MIT)
// Copyright (c) 2020, Notionovus, LLC.
var array5bit_A = new Array ( 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB', 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/', 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAB', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAB', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAD/', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAB', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAAB', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAB', 'SL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+', 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAB', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
var array5bit_B = new Array ( 'US0CAuSD38g', 'UUYCA7QBErs', 'ajEDAm49ReY', 'UUoCA+juogg', 'bjEDAjQrOn0', 'bkoDA3iPVH4', 'ajUDAt82atY', 'UU4CA1nljTg', 'cjEDAghkmFU', 'ckoDA0TA9lY', 'izUEAhrxcbg', 'ck4DAxY8F10', 'bjUDAlvFFR8', 'bk4DAxdhexw', 'ajkDAr7LFAw', 'UVICAyQ+UJI', 'TTECAq7UnEM', 'TUoCA+Jw8kA', 'ZjUDAmZGozo', 'TU4CA7CME0s', 'ajUDAvnk9E4', 'ak4DA7VAmk0', 'ZjkDAtle3bI', 'TVICAxOyzrM', 'STUCAqHeHtM', 'SU4CA+16cNA', 'h6QEAZKdo54', 'SVICA62zYxM', 'RTkCAqx1lb4', 'RVICA/z3WM0', 'QT0CAkdoxRU', 'KFYBA46vJCA');
var stringStart = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/A';
var stringMid = 'AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
var stringEnd = 'AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="';

var fltHeight = 2.1;
var fltWidth = 4.0;

function genBarcode(inputString,intWidth,intHeight) {
   var intRawmod = inputString.length % 5;
   if (intRawmod > 0) for (var i = 0; i < 5 - intRawmod; i++) inputString += "0";
   var arraySeq = new Array (intChunks = inputString.length / 5);
   for (var i = 0; i < intChunks; i++) arraySeq[i] = parseInt(inputString.substr(i * 5, 5), 2);
   var resultString = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < arraySeq.length; i++) resultString += stringStart + array5bit_A[arraySeq[i]] + stringMid + array5bit_B[arraySeq[i]] + stringEnd + intWidth + '" height="' + intHeight + '">';
   return resultString;
}

var buttonBarcode = document.getElementById("btnGenBar");
buttonBarcode.onclick = function () {
  strResult = "";
 fltWidth = document.getElementById("textWidth").value;
 fltHeight = document.getElementById("textHeight").value;
 for (var loop = 0; loop < pdf417Barby.length; loop++) {
  strText = pdf417Barby[loop];
  strResult += '<div style="height:' + fltHeight + 'px">' + genBarcode(strText, fltWidth, fltHeight) + "</div>";
 }
 document.getElementById("resultBarby").innerHTML = strResult;
 strResult = "";
 for (var loop = 0; loop < pdf417IDA.length; loop++) {
  strText = "";
  for (var innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < pdf417IDA[loop].length; innerLoop++) {
    chrOctal = pdf417IDA[loop].charAt(innerLoop);
    strBinary = parseInt(chrOctal).toString(2);
    while ( strBinary.length < 3 ) strBinary = '0' + strBinary;
    strText += strBinary;
  }
  strResult += '<div style="height:' + fltHeight + 'px">' + genBarcode(strText, fltWidth, fltHeight) + "</div>";
 }
 document.getElementById("resultIDA").innerHTML = strResult;
}

var pdf417Barby = ["11111111010101000111010110111100001100100000100110011101100100011000111000110110111001110010001000111010010001000010000100001101110011001101001000001100011101010111000000110000110001000101010011101110000010101000001000000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111111010110111101110101110000011011110101110011100110101110000100001000011101011111011100000100011010100001110101111101011111010000111011100011001110100111100010000010101111101100100010011110101101100000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000110101000011111001100011111010001010000111100100010100000110010011101101010111110000010101000111100000111100101111010001101100001001111011111010111001000100011101100011101000111011000111010101100111110000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000101001000010000001000010011101110011110011101001100111101111010001001100011000010010010001100110010000101100111000110001100001100010001011000011011001100100010000110001101101110011000100011101001001110000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000110101111001100001011111010000111011000001001110010100010011111011001110011011101000010111110100001110100001110101111101110101110000011011110100000101000111010111001100001010111111011100011110101111011110111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111010111110010001000011110010001010001111000010100100001111001000101000011110010001010111111011100010101001100111110001111110010110001010111111011110110110110001011110001011001101111000011010111111001000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111101000101111001011011101100000011001100001100110101101110011000001011100111000100011101111000110010110100001100011101000110110001000010101100011000000111001100000101101110011011101111010100111100111100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111110100100001101011100010011111011101001100000010110011000011110101111010010010000011110101000100000101001111110111001100110001111010010100011110000100101000111100001001010001111000010011111010010001100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111111010011101101111001011110100011011010000011110100001101000111001111101000011101011001111010011000100011101110111101101111100010001010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111011111010011110110111111101000101001", "11111111010101000101000010010000001000010011101110011110011101001100100000100010001001100111001110011010000100111011100100001001110111001000010011101110011110011101001100100000100010001001110001100001011010100011110111100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000101001111001000001111000100000101011110001000001010111100010000010101111000100000101010001111001011110111000110011101001111000100000101011110001000001010111100010000010101111000100000101011010011110110000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000101000110011111001100111101001100010000001101011100110111110001001001101111100010010011011111000100100110111110001001001101111100010010011011111000100100100111100001001001000111011101111011110100011110010111111101000101001", "11111111010101000110100000100001101001110011100100010011100111001000100111001110010001100001100010001011000011000100010100001100110010001000010100010000011110011100101100100001000110001101101001100001110011101000001001110111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111010001100010001111011100011101011011101111100100110001101111010001111000010010010011010111110011100101111011011111001111000100000101011110001000001010111100010000010101111000100000101011101000110010000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000100101011110000001000111011000111010001110110001110110011110100110001000000110101110010011110000100100100011101110111101001111000010010010001110111011110100111100001001001000111011101111010010100011110000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000100101100001100001100111001110011010000100111011100100001001110111001100001100011011011001110011100110100001001110111001000010011101110010000100111011100110000110001101101001110011100100011001011001110000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111110100001001101000011101011111011100001000110100111000010001101001011110110111110011110001000001010100011110010111101110001100111010011110001000001010111110110010001001011111001000111011111010000101100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111001011111010001000000110100111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111011001011111100100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000110110110110000001111001110100110010000010001000100111000110000101101000010011101110010000110011100110111011100110011001111001100010111011100011011011100111001000100011101011001110011000011101101000001100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111010000011000101011110110111110011110001000001010100110001111101001100010111000010011110101110111000101111011011111001111000100000101011110001000001010111100010000010101111000100000101011110100000110110111111101000101001", "11111111010101000110010010001111101000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101100011111001010011011111000100100100001111001000101001111000010010011111100100110100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000100100111001110001000110111100111011100011000010110100001001110111001000010011101110011110011101001100100000100010001001000110001100001010001101111001110100111001110010001001110011100100010110111000011000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111001011001000001011110110111110011110001000001010111110110010001001000000101111010010011110010111100111100010000010101111000100000101011110001000001010111110110010001001011111001001110011110010110110000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111011011111100101000000110100111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010110010011100000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111011001100111001000010011101110010000100100000010101110111000010001101100001000010011100111010010000110011100111001101000010011101110010000100111011100100001001110111001000010011101110011001000100110000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000110010111100001101111000100000101011110001000001010111100010000010101101110001111101010111110100001110111000010001101001110001100111010011110001000001010111100010000010101111000100000101011001011110001100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000101100111001111101111100010011101010000011100101100100001111001000101000000110101110010011110000100100100011101110111101001111000010010010001110111011110100111100001001001000111011101111011101100111111010111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111011000101100001000110001100001010001101111001110100011000110000101000110111100111010001100011000010100011011110011101000110001100001010001101111001110110011100111001101000010010000001010010001110001110111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111101101100010001100010111000010011000100011110110110011000011110101101011100000100011110100100100000111101000100000101011110110111110011110001000001010111100010000010101111000100000101011111011011001100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000101100001000111001000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010001110110001110100011101100011101000111011000111010110000010111000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000100100001100110001000010011101110010000100111011100100001001110111001000010011101110010000100111011100100001001110111001000010010000001010111011100001000110001000001001101110011101001000010110001100000100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000110110111100001001110000100011010011100001000110100111000010001101001011110110111110011111011001000100100111100010111101001111001011110011110001000001010100110001111101001100010111000010011011011110001000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000100010111011111101101110100011100010011110100100000110101011111000001111110010111011011010011111100010100011101000110001000010010111100011111001011101000100111101001000001010111000111111011000101111110100111111101000101001", "11111111010101000100100000100000101111001110100110010000110001100100100001100011001001000011000110010010000110001100100100001100011001001110111100110001011100010001001110100001000010100001011000011101100011001000001000110111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111110110010001001111010010001000011100010111000110101000111100010001001111101000111010111101001111000111000101100001001111000001010100011100010001100010111100010001001001110001101110010011111101100100110111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111111000100110101101001100111111010100000100011110101111011101110001010000100001111010001111000101000101001110111111001000111010110000011100010011111010110111110001010001011000011011110011111000100111010111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111000101100111101000011011000001011011011001100000101000001010000001110100111011111010011011110111000100001100111001101000101110111000011110011110100010100011100111000101110101101111000011000101101110000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000110110011110001001011111101001100011111000011010010111001110111100101101000011110110010110111111011000110000101110010001100110011110001010010011110000100111101000110110001111010111000111011011001111001000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000101110110111000001100111000101110011010011011111100111111010110001001000010011011111011101001011111100111001001011111101100110010111100011111010000111010101000000101111001100111110001001010111011000111000111111101000101001", "11111111010101000111000100100111001000101110001110010111011110110000101000010001000001100110011100111011101110010100000111000110110111001100001101101100010011011100001100100011000110010001111011110110110011100010010111000111111101000101001"];
var pdf417IDA = ["777777770707070007737352123166300076631353225166610734303675155600007111427613176322077740145751563460750112671207373307462673170014623076600377166364430764227111623264707206231512236203072202551566304630740621733221460107662617154430221076311157202731250704117660656332207440533422766013077771707415447400777777707000707007", "777777770707070007574363351354550072313512245101460770433551033675207467512777271774076462315526366430725123004422375207723531663457220072657406674037100764401175263464107243110276220673074026137726740230702267312642323507651004714437752072652177441755110762661351203600107735245473154564077161273111541300777777707000707007", "777777770707070007373074471114744075005377074633220750053770746332207500537707463322077205157054631200750013770306332607440537217563333074000377120722270740003771207222707004473356432623074000377120722270740003771207222707620037712272007076022355122722070760223551227220707602235512272207077372124135523000777777707000707007", "777777770707070007735210263753230070266713744326230720445317663062107226653356410601070044733564326230722445335663040307026671374432623072044531766306210762220671214131407005573246432632070045732575237330700557324643263207000573217523337074451376424326720744017761712733307445177642432272077170122611550300777777707000707007", "777777770707070007372030142315331074440377524326630744403775243266307664037752632443072026715566326470760223551227220707620215512270027074022177322502050762221751007022507400017532270205074000377120722270700447335643262307400037712072227070044733564326230700446235652373207400037712072227073702101621311510777777707000707007", "777777770707070007772070551355651076000157122700250740003771207222707000077356472667074404773164326630744403771207266707440037716436663074400733160326670740442275612777207445137642432672074441376535237730744403775243266307445137642432672075441773434673220750017330346376607104177303067322071340563333154330777777707000707007", "777777770707070007631611404621131077463355436237420774633554362374207302771547623746073027711076233060730277154762374607306771147623702073265711456015020752233750124332407700315503261106075203377210433040730277514766334607702335507627702073027751476633460730673554366330207742375143267302076334314004611310777777707000707007", "777777770707070007336314652757330077473254426337520765337055626774607302765157772346072077355437723120760663111623224307642264516327312072215530044122160766411565152357107665137642632452076463354537237530764733544263265207646335453723753076473354426326520764633545372375307647335442632652077325124741155740777777707000707007", "777777770707070007552072225115741073207717674017440730277110762330607302771547623746073027711076233060730277154762374607302771107623306077463355436237420774637514366730207702371103663746073063751032673020730237514722730207702335503263306073023351076233460774277114322374207306331547267702077502522271137450777777707000707007", "777777770707070007277204655201577075441277535327620757633757141076207664015750432461076651157405324610767412665373244207656324553722642076642155526304630754620777361065107767317550530760077440057536324730744412664342377307555166343576322074011732124726660703637700035733107502313723601740076770460134075510777777707000707007", "777777770707070007314201277155021072011772126623420722317500374027107301055313762162071323651317622500732235731246104107203377022672252073133562334511610712317733275225007111174323750071071112472337502610712307722355315007222275223561153073220461216511510712276334651335507237435772313773077126032375134450777777707000707007"]
```

```html
<head>
<title>PDF417 Example</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" id="btnGenBar" value="Generate Barcode" tabindex=4/>
 &nbsp;↕&nbsp;<input type="text" id="textHeight" size="2" maxlength="3" tabindex=2 value="2.1"/>
 &nbsp;↔&nbsp;<input type="text" id="textWidth" size="2" maxlength="3" tabindex=3 value="4.0"/>
 <p>Barby:</p>
 <div id="resultBarby"></div>
 <p style="margin-top: 100px">ID Automation:</p>
 <div id="resultIDA"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In short, you are going to have to use the ID Automation encoder on the client side of your API. Or find an encoder that works with the Barby binary to generate the graphic.